# Wording for the "edit" link text

Tags: text, hyperlinks, wording

I'm building a website that's in many ways similar to StackExchange but more focused on other topics and differently structured.

Now, I've come to the links text wording.. Particularly, the "*edit*" one;

I've thought to call it just "*edit*" but maybe the users could be confused and wrongly think that's their "personal" content, because even non-authors will be able to edit that content.

Would be "*improve this content*" better? But I don't want to copy the wordings of StackExchange as that feels bad and it looks also pretty long.

So what do you think is the best choice to go, suggestions?

Comment: Where do you want to place the "edit" link? If you put it under a question like here (as far as I understood you'll build a Q&A site), so the user should think he will edit his own profile...

Comment: I don't get your doubts about the "personal" content, can you clarify your question?

Comment: @dTDesign Below the content and yes it's a sort of Q&A site basically. He will edit another user content but it shouldn't feel like "his" content to be clear.

Comment: If you are starting up a Stack Exchange competitor and your legal name is Jeff Atwood, you should either go by a pseudonym for all things related to your site or get it legally changed. _Life will be better for you_. On the other hand, if you are trolling that would kind of defeat the purpose now wouldn't it?

Comment: @Caleb No it's not a Stack Exchange competitor. It's more of a niche site about anarchy and related topics. Why do I have to change my name if it's mine? Regarding the trolling insinuation read my biography as I'm tired to explain it everytime. Enough, don't spam the comments section of this answer if your argument isn't related to it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you are talking about the edit button/option on posts, you can be clear and direct, something like "edit this post", or "edit this message".

If the post and the options are enclosed on a box or on the same area delimited by something like a shadow, the "this" used on the button is very clear. If you don't have that kind of design and everything seems to be "floating", like in this site, then the "this" may feel more related to tags or other elements that you have on your pages.

The same could apply to the comments area, if you have one. Although, since the comments area is smaller, you can use just "edit", is clear, direct and is close enough to the content so there should be no problems or doubts.

All the consideration that involve distance, are dependant on your design. Which we haven't seen.

Answer (score 2):

A simple stroll through [Thesaurus.com's list of synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/edit) should help you decide what you like, if anything.  If nothing jumps out, simply stay with ***edit***:

[image: screen shot for edit synonyms]

I don't think you'd have any issues with ***edit***, as it's pretty standard.

That said, if you *really* want to go with something else, I'd go with one of these, from the list above:

- ***revise***
- ***adapt***
- ***alter***

Out of those three, I think ***revise*** is the one I'd ultimately go with.

Comment: Let's start butchering some SO posts. :D

Comment: @ThiefMaster - That _would_ be a funny one to use.  SO should have themed days where all of their links are renamed to represent that theme. That link would be for _American Psycho Day_! Hahaha ...

Answer (score 1):

"edit" is fine. You could use it more verbosely e.g. "edit this content" "edit this page"

I can't see an issue with edit being confused with yours or someone else's content. If the author of the post is displayed that is.

Comment: Well in my website you cross the line between a social network and a wiki Q&A site (but it also is a community news like Reddit), so it is tricky.

Comment: ive edited my answer based on a comment you made above about it being a q&a site. I see no real issue with edit